# Show/hide list items and add more/less link

Tags: jquery, append, toggle

I need some help with showing/hiding list items after nth-child and appending more/less link dependent of parent class. How would I append a list item with the less link if the parent has class "expanded"?

The problem with the code I have so far (see below) is that I append the "more" link initially even if the parent has class "expanded". Once the item has been clicked, it functions properly.

You can also check the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/1nkus8en/2/)

```js
$('ul.expandible').each(function(){
    var lis = $(this).find('li:gt(4)');
    if(!$(this).hasClass('expanded')) {
        lis.hide();
    } else {
        lis.show();
    }
    
    if(lis.length>0){
        $(this).append($('<li class="expand"><span>More</span></li>').click(function(event){
            var $expandible = $(this).parents('.expandible');
            $expandible.toggleClass('expanded');
            if ( !$expandible.hasClass('expanded')) {
                $(this).text('More');
            } else {
                $(this).text('Less');
            };
            lis.toggle();
            event.preventDefault();
        }));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>First List with "expanded" class loaded</h3>
<ul class="expandible expanded">
    <li>Option 1</li>
    <li>Option 2</li>
    <li>Option 3</li>
    <li>Option 4</li>
    <li>Option 5</li>
    <li>Option 6</li>
    <li>Option 7</li>
</ul>

<h3>Second List without "expanded" class</h3>
<ul class="expandible">
    <li>Option 1</li>
    <li>Option 2</li>
    <li>Option 3</li>
    <li>Option 4</li>
    <li>Option 5</li>
    <li>Option 6</li>
    <li>Option 7</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. Try this;

```js
$('ul.expandible').each(function(){
    var $ul = $(this),
        $lis = $ul.find('li:gt(4)'),
        isExpanded = $ul.hasClass('expanded');
    $lis[isExpanded ? 'show' : 'hide']();
    
    if($lis.length > 0){
        $ul
            .append($('<li class="expand"><span>' + (isExpanded ? 'Less' : 'More') + '</span></li>')
            .click(function(event){
                var isExpanded = $ul.hasClass('expanded');
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).text(isExpanded ? 'More' : 'Less');
                $ul.toggleClass('expanded');
                $lis.toggle();
            }));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>First List with "expanded" class loaded</h3>
<ul class="expandible expanded">
    <li>Option 1</li>
    <li>Option 2</li>
    <li>Option 3</li>
    <li>Option 4</li>
    <li>Option 5</li>
    <li>Option 6</li>
    <li>Option 7</li>
</ul>

<h3>Second List without "expanded" class loaded</h3>
<ul class="expandible">
    <li>Option 1</li>
    <li>Option 2</li>
    <li>Option 3</li>
    <li>Option 4</li>
    <li>Option 5</li>
    <li>Option 6</li>
    <li>Option 7</li>
</ul>
```

I was in a hurry, so my answer was a little bit short. Sorry about that. Now explanations:

1. Prefix your jQuery objects with a `$` sign.
2. Cache your jQuery variables for future use if you're going to use them more then once, like `$ul = $(this);`
3. You can use jQuery methods like array elements. Combining it with a ternary operator you can use shortcuts like this: `$lis[isExpanded ? 'show' : 'hide']();`

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, much obliged. I like the way you solved it with "isExpanded" and the ternary operator. Haven't come to that chapter yet ;)

Comment: I updated my answer. I made some code review and added some explanation.

Comment: I changed the code myself and applied the ternary operator to the text as well using "isExpanded", but this solution is much cleaner.